# how to pass second button on click over the first button to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and html . I have a small question. I have some thing like the following in the javascript file.

```
function setColor(btn, color)
{
if (btn.style.backgroundColor == "#f47121") {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = color;
} else {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = "#f47121";
}
}

<input type="submit" value="Review & Next" name="b1" onclick="setColor(this,'#fff200');" />
<input type="submit" value="1" name="b2" />
```

my question is how to pass the second button as function argument when click the first button instead of 'this' i use b2 ,but it not worked can anyone help please

Comment: Please note that browsers return different formats for _color_ properties, so your condition will fail in some browsers. You can toggle a className instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the id instead.

set the id to 'b2' and then inside the function find it and set it.
You no longer have to use `this` anymore .. whatever id you pass in the function will use that instead.

```
<input type="submit" value="Review & Next" name="b1" id="b1" onclick="setColor('b2','#fff200');" />
<input type="submit" value="1" name="b2" id="b2"/>
```

You can now pass any of them to the function

```
function setColor(arg, color)
{
   var btn = document.getElementById(arg);

if (btn.style.backgroundColor == "#f47121") {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = color;
} else {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = "#f47121";
}
}
```